# How many axis of symmetry of the cube are there?

Tags: geometry, rubiks-cube

In my final mathematics test, I have a bonus question: How many axis of symmetry of the cube are there?

The teacher gives me the definition:

> **Definition:** If we rotate a 3-dimension object around the line d for 180 degrees and it result in an exactly same shape in an exactly same position, line d is a **axis of symmetry** of that object.

I have found 9 axis of symmetry, 3 of which pass through the centers of 2 opposite faces, the other 6 pass through the midpoints of the 2 opposite edges. But my teacher told that 9 is wrong and said that the correct answer is not what we're going to expect.

So, what is the correct answer? And how can we prove it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry

Comment: Your teacher must have misled you. The correct answer is 13.

Comment: Are you sure only $180$ degree rotations are allowed? A cube has $3$-fold rotational symmetry about an axis which passes through two opposite corners.

Comment: @vadim123: Acually the definition of my teacher is not the same as usual. It's is related to rotation, and 'real' symmetry probably won't work.

Comment: @kccu: At the start, I also count the line pass 2 opposite corners. But then I notice that it won't result in the same thing when rotated by 180 degree.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: So what are the 4 axis I've missed?

Comment: Four axes, each passing through opposite corners of the cube.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: No, it won't result in the same thing. I've experimented with the Rublk's Cube.

Comment: @LêĐứcMinh That's why I said $3$-fold symmetry. You get the same thing if you rotate by $120$ degrees. Typically that would also be considered an axis of symmetry, which is why I asked about your definition specifically stating $180$ degrees only.

Comment: @kccu: Yep, 3-fold symmetry isn't counted.

Comment: Then your answer is correct.

Comment: Nine symmetries looks right to me, once you restrict to 180 degree rotations. For any axis of symmetry according to your definition is also an axis of a rotation in the more general notion of symmetry group. A look at the wiipedia page shows 24 symmetries, but one is the identity, leaving 23, and 6 are 90 degree rotations about one of the coordinate axes, leaving 17, and 8 more are rotations of 120 degrees around main diagonals, leaving...nine.

Comment: Your teacher therefore has the wrong answer.

Comment: There is something interesting. A cube has $12$ edges and $13 $($=12+1$) axes of symmetry. $6$ of them are of order $2$ (and $6\times 2=12$), $4$ of them are of order $3$ (and $4\times 3=12$) and $3$ of them are of order $4$ (and $3\times 4=12$). A regular dodecahedron has $30$ edges and $31$ axes of symmetry. $15$ of them are of order $2$, $10$ of them are of order $3$ and $6$ of them are of order $5$. And we have $15\times2=10\times3=6\times5=30$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An axis of symmetry can only passes through

(1) mid-points of two opposite edges. (As a cube has 12 edges, there are $12\div2=6$ axes of this type.)

(2) two opposite vertices. (As a cube has 8 vertices, there are $8\div2=4$ axes of this type.)

(3) the centres of two opposite faces.  (As a cube has 6 faces, there are $6\div2=3$ axes of this type.)

So it has $13$ axes of symmetry.

Note: The number of symmetry is equal to

$$\frac{E}{2}+\frac{V}{2}+\frac{F}{2}=\frac{E}{2}+\frac{E+2}{2}=E+1$$